# PhpStorm Xdebug not working in WSL when running files in CLI

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2. My Xdebug is configured and triggers PhpStorm breakpoints when browsing the local dev site on chrome, just as it should.

However when running PHP scripts through CLI (php test.php) PhpStorm notices the connection and halts but there is no breakpoints, I cannot interact, nothing happens.

Xdebug Settings:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.log = "/var/www/html/test.log"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=172.28.192.1
xdebug.client_port=9000
;xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log_level = 7
```

Output of Xdebug log when trying to run script in CLI.

```
[14214] Log opened at 2021-05-15 00:41:14.790013
[14214] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.28.192.1:9000.
[14214] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.28.192.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/dev_test/test/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14214"><engine version="3.0.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 7 -c 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="7" success="1"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- status -i 8
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="8" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 9
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="9" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/dev_test/test/test.php" lineno="2"></xdebug:message></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 10 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="10"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NTSF9DT05ORUNUSU9OJ10p
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9BRERSJ10p
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 14 -t line -f file:////wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/var/www/dev_test/test/test.php -n 10
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="14" id="142140001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 15
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="15"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/dev_test/test/test.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 16
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="16"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/dev_test/test/test.php" lineno="2"></stack></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 17
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="17"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 18 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzJlN2M3ZjYzLTFjNDEtNDgwMS04ZDA2LWMyYzIwZGQ4MzZhNCddPSR1X29iag==
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="18"><property type="null"></property></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 19 -d 0 -c 0
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="19" context="0"><property name="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE" fullname="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE" type="array" children="1" numchildren="1" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="2e7c7f63-1c41-4801-8d06-c2c20dd836a4" fullname="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE[&quot;2e7c7f63-1c41-4801-8d06-c2c20dd836a4&quot;]" type="null"></property></property><property name="$db" fullname="$db" type="uninitialized"></property><prope
[14214] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 20 -d 0 -c 1
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="20" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_ENV" fullname="$_ENV" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><property name="$_FILES" fullname="$_FILES" type="array" children="0" numchildren="0" page="0" pagesize="100"></property><pro
[14214] [Step Debug] <- run -i 21
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <stream xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" type="stdout" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[CkRlYnVnIEJ1ZmZlcgo9PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09Ck1lbW9yeSBVc2FnZTogNDY3ODY0MCBCdWZmZXIgU2l6ZTogNwotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tCkRFQlVHIFtMMDM5OV0gWzEzNTEybXNdOiBHTE9CQUw6IFVSSTogdGVzdC5waHAgSVAgQWRkcmVzczogCkRFQlVHIFtMMDQwMF0gWzEzNTEy
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="21" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[14214] [Step Debug] <- detach -i 22
[14214] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="detach" transaction_id="22" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[14214] Log closed at 2021-05-15 00:41:28.327542
```

Comment: Please show the same Xdebug log for a successful debug session (for the same file/URL). From what I see: IDE sets the breakpoint using `//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/var/www/timetrex_test/test/test.php` path but the correct path here should be without the leading `//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04` part. So I just want to see what path is used there.

Comment: If the path for web debug is correct then it looks like you may need to set the `serverName` via ENV so the IDE knows what `PHP | Servers` entry to use to do a correct path mapping. That's if you launch such CLI debug in a terminal yourself and not by using PHP Script type of Run/Debug Configuration from within the IDE (where IDE should be covering such moment).

Comment: Correct on regular browsing dev site the paths are "filename="file:///var/www" without the //wsl$. Also correct running the script directly in PhpStorm with debug (right click -> file debug) does trigger the breakpoints, but not run (right click file -> run). I assume set that serverName in WSL or windows where PhpStorm is ran?

Comment: 1) *"right click file -> run"* It should not trigger the debug. I mean: yes, your Xdebug is configured to try and debug every single request ... but PhpStorm should also be ready for incoming debug connections... When you click Debug it starts listening for incoming debug requests but not when you are using Run. So if you want to use debug when you use Run, you should also ensure that the green "phone handle" icon is ON.

Comment: 2) When you use Debug button and it's a CLI, the IDE also sets custom ENV variable where it passes some extra params. One of them should be the connection (server) name (so IDE knows how to map local path to the remote one). You should use Debug button to start debugging from IDE -- it simply makes things much easier for you. Double check the official docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html#starting-cli-debugging-session

Comment: If you need to initiate the debug from the remote (e.g. a cron task etc) then look at this (in addition to your current Xdebug config (which is good) & "phone handle" icon in the IDE). The `PHP_IDE_CONFIG` environment variable should be set to `serverName=SomeName` where `SomeName` is the name of the server configured on the `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Servers` page -- look into this / mentioned on the link above.

Comment: Sorry for late rely, that environment variable completely fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Actually one last issue. "php test.php" and running scripts from command line works. But running my unit tests from file "sudo ./run.sh" from CLI does not trigger the breakpoints using that bash script runs which paraunit and phpunit.

Comment: But not a big deal, I can right click -> debug any of the failed tests and it works. Just won't trigger breakpoints from run.sh.